# What do I change in my config to access my local NXT NRS Server/Client from another computer on my local LAN?

Tags: server, nxt

I just installed and unzipped the NXT server/client from: https://bitbucket.org/JeanLucPicard/nxt/downloads

The run.sh file is running fine now and I can access the NRS (NXT Reference Software) via localhost:7876 on the computer that is running the server.

But now I want to be able to access this server on another computer on the network. I know the IP address of the computer running the server, but I can't seem to get to the NRS. I know I have to make some changes on the config file, but what are the sections I need to make changes to?

Can someone list out what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

what I did was the following, create a nxt.properties file in the conf/ directory and put this in the file:

This basically makes your NXT NRS server publicly available on your local lan or via the internet if your looking to setup a public server.

```
# Hosts from which to allow http/json API requests, if enabled. Set to * to allow all.
# Can also specify networks in CIDR notation, e.g. 192.168.1.0/24.
#nxt.allowedBotHosts=127.0.0.1; localhost; [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1];
nxt.allowedBotHosts=*; localhost; [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1];


# Host interface on which to listen for http/json API request, default localhost only.
# Set to 0.0.0.0 to allow the API server to accept requests from all network interfaces.
#nxt.apiServerHost=127.0.0.1
nxt.apiServerHost=0.0.0.0


# Hosts from which to allow NRS user interface requests, if enabled. Set to * to allow all.
#nxt.allowedUserHosts=127.0.0.1; localhost; [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1];
nxt.allowedUserHosts=*; localhost; [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1];


# Host interface for NRS user interface server, default localhost only.
# Set to 0.0.0.0 to allow the UI to be accessed on all network interfaces.
#nxt.uiServerHost=127.0.0.1
nxt.uiServerHost=0.0.0.0
```